# How to prove : If $a,b,c$ are in H.P. in $\Delta ABC$ then $\frac{(\sum ab-2bc ) ( \sum ab-2ca)}{(abc)^2} = \frac{\sin A}{\Delta} -\frac{1}{b^2} $

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

How to prove : If $a,b,c$ are in H.P. in $\Delta ABC$ then $$\frac{(\sum ab-2bc ) ( \sum ab-2ca)}{(abc)^2}=\frac{\sin A}{\Delta} -\frac{1}{b^2} $$

Please guide how to proceed , will be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: What is $\Delta$? The area of the triangle? And the sums in the numerator of LHS are cyclic?

Comment: If $\Delta$ is the area of the triangle, then it is given by $\frac{1}{2} bc \sin A$ and that cancels out $\sin A$ in the RHS. After that, it should be straightforward (using the fact that $1/a + 1/c = 2/b$).

Comment: Aren't both sums not the same?

Comment: I got for the first sum $$ab-2bc+ba-2ab+ca-2ab=-ab-bc-ca$$

Comment: and for the second one $$ab-2ca+bc-2ab+ca-2bc$$ and this is $$-ab-ca-bc$$

Comment: Ok, i have forgotten, that $a,b,c$ are in a H.P.

Comment: Now i got $$\frac{(a+c) (3 a+5 c)}{2 a^2 c^2}\neq 0$$

Answer (score 0):

As $$\triangle=\dfrac{bc\sin A}2$$

So,we need $$\dfrac{(ab+ca-bc)(ab+bc-ca)}{(abc)^2}=\dfrac{2b-c}{b^2c}$$

$$\iff(ab)^2-(bc-ca)^2=a^2c(2b-c)$$

$$\iff a^2b^2-b^2c^2=2a^2bc-2abc^2$$

$$\iff b(a^2-c^2)=2ca(a-c)$$

As  in general, $a-c\ne0$ unless $a=b=c$ $$b(a+c)=2ca\iff\dfrac1a+\dfrac1c=\dfrac2b$$